# Spotifyr Error: INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI

Tags: r, spotify

I am trying to use the spotifyr package to extract the data from Spotify however any function that requires an access token is not working (e.g. get_my_recently_played(limit = 5)). I get the following error when I run it: INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI.

I have even tried going to My Application and changing the Redirect URIs to 'http://localhost:8888/callback/' but it still gives the same error. What might I be missing here? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()
```

per the readme at https://github.com/charlie86/spotifyr?

UPDATE:

```
This works for me with the version of `spotifyr` available on CRAN
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id_here')
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'your_client_secret_here')

access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()

library(spotifyr)

get_artist_audio_features('the beatles')
```

Comment: Yes. I have. Still no success :(

Comment: you may want to install from cran directly with `install.packages('spotifyr')` if you had installed the dev version from github, but I just went through the app registration process with spotify and was able to get the package to work with my credentials, please see my edited answer

Comment: That one works for me too. Can you try get_my_recently_played(limit = 5). Thats where I am having the issue

Comment: Also I have the dev version installed because I think the cran version does not have the get_my_recently_played function

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding your question, I've installed dev version and replicated the error, it seems like this could be submitted as an issue on the repo

Answer (score 2):

Try to set this redirect URL in Spotify API Client settings to http://localhost:1410/

I had the same issue and this URL works for me now

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup the callback URL in the settings for your app on the Developer Dashboard.

Simply log in, find your app and click "Edit Settings" in the top right section. Under redirect URIs you add `http://localhost:8888/callback` and remember to click save in the bottom. This should resolve your issue.